# How to get multiple sentences in arrays into a single response in python?

Tags: python, arrays, amazon-web-services

As a hobby, I started doing a project with amazon textract which helps in extracting text from a photo or a pdf. Now I ran into a problem. According to what I read from it's docs, every word in the photo is a small "block". When I try printing, it prints fine, but if I have to use that text to send somewhere, like an email etc, I need the whole text as a single file. So I would need all blocks of texts to be stored in a single response to help my further use. This is where I am stuck for a few days. Help appreciated. Thank you

```
def processor(name):
    textract = boto3.client('textract')
    response = textract.detect_document_text(
        Document = {
            'S3Object':{
                'Bucket':bucketName,
                'Name':name
            }
        }
        
     )
    for item in response["Blocks"]:
        if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
            print (item["Text"])
```

Comment: Can't you just change `print (item["Text"])` to instead add the line to a string variable? Or an array that you then join with newline to create a string? I don't know python so can't give a code example.

Comment: It looks like the whole text is already in a single response...?  Would this do what you wanted? `'\n'.join([item['Text'] for item in response["Blocks"] if item["BlockType"] == "LINE"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one liner below should do the job

```
single_response = ' '.join(item["Text"] for item in response["Blocks"] if item["BlockType"] == "LINE")
```